# Zend_Date localized date

Tags: mysql, date, zend-framework, localization

I am having a date of the format "2015-05-01 00:00:00" and I also have the locale to which it belongs to example : en_US, de_DE. I need to convert this date(just date) to the localised date format. I tried using something like,

```
 $locale='en_US';
 $testDate = new Zend_Date($dateLocale, null, new Zend_Locale($locale));
 $testDate->toString();
```

I get the output as `Jan 5, 2015 12:00:00 AM`

I am expecting `05/01/15`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var_dump($testDate->get(Zend_Date::DATE_SHORT , $locale));
```